# aws-s3 and European Buckets

Tags: ruby, actionscript-3

Is there a work around for European Buckets and aws-s3 with RoR?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem you're having with the European buckets?  Code examples and error messages would be helpful.

Comment: There is a well-known bug with aws-s3 and european buckets and I  can't find out what's going on with it..

Answer (score 3):

In an initializer, you should add this line :

`AWS::S3::DEFAULT_HOST.replace "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"`

Here is the open issue on the github project.

https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3/issues#issue/4

Answer (score 0):

The workaround could be to use [a fixed fork of the AWS::S3 library](http://github.com/isaacfeliu/aws-s3)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "[s3](https://github.com/qoobaa/s3)" gem instead. That suports the european buckets as well.

Answer (score 0):

This one also works with European buckets. I use it all the time for the London region. It's called [Commandeer](https://getcommandeer.com). Super handy while debugging your S3 integration.

[image]